# Can't cross compile gdb/gdbserver

Tags: compiler-errors, cross-platform

Im trying to cross compile OpenWrt-RTK gdb/gdbserver package, I selected gdbserver in `make menuconfig` and executed `make V=s` but I cant compile it, Im getting this error

```
../sim/mips/libsim.a -lreadline ../opcodes/libopcodes.a ../bfd/libbfd.a  ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a    -ldl -lncurses -lz -lm  ../libiberty/libiberty.a  build-gnulib/import/libgnu.a -ldl -Wl,--dynamic-list=./proc-service.list
remote.o: In function `remote_g_packet_data_init':
remote.c:(.text+0x2124): undefined reference to `_obstack_newchunk'
gdbtypes.o: In function `make_qualified_type':
gdbtypes.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `_obstack_newchunk'
gdbtypes.o: In function `alloc_type':
gdbtypes.c:(.text+0x3b8): undefined reference to `_obstack_newchunk'
gdbtypes.c:(.text+0x44c): undefined reference to `_obstack_newchunk'
gdbtypes.o: In function `make_function_type':
```

[This patch](http://uclibc.10924.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-include-obstack-h-do-not-hide-obstack-newchunk-td12986.html) is already applay-ed  and here is full log https://pastebin.com/nA6nGzU2

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line `#define ELIDE_CODE` in libiberty/obstack.c solved issue